# IWbemLocator::ConnectServer (WMI) crashes in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-10, wmi

I am writing a simple x86 application for extracting Harddrive/storage info by using WMI. The development environment is MS Visual Studio 2013 Update 5. However, everytime my code reaches this part :

```
hr = (*pLoc)->ConnectServer(....);
```

I receive this error

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x6C2BD183 (wbemcomn.dll) in HDDExtractor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00DB9CAA"
```

The funny thing is that, this error occurs on the PCs with Windows 7, however it always works perfectly fine on PCs with Windows 10.

Below is the excerpt of the source code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Winbase.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <WinIoCtl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")
////////////////////////////////////////
#include <icmpapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <strsafe.h>
//////////////////////////////////////
//for WMI
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <wbemidl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
/////////////////////////////
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>

std::string WMI_Initialize(IWbemServices **pSvc, IWbemLocator **pLoc)
{
    //Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoInitializeEx(0,  COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::string result;
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
        result = out.str();
        return result;
    }


    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,                        // Security descriptor    
        -1,                          // COM negotiates authentication service
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication level for proxies
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation level for proxies
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities of the client or server
        NULL);                       // Reserved

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::string result;
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        result = out.str();
        return result;
    }

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&pLoc[0]);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        string result;
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hr << endl;
        result = out.str();
        CoUninitialize();
        return result;
    }

    // Connect to the root\default namespace with the current user.
    hr = (*pLoc)->ConnectServer(
        BSTR(L"\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2"),
        NULL,       // User name 
        NULL,       // User password
        0,         // Locale 
        NULL,     // Security flags
        0,         // Authority 
        0,        // Context object 
        &pSvc[0]);   // IWbemServices proxy
    // The rest/other stuffs below
}
```

And this is the calling function

```
std::string WMI_getHDDSN(std::string str)
{
    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;
    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    HRESULT hr;

    std::string result = WMI_Initialize(&pSvc, &pLoc);
    //The rest/other stuffs are below
}
```

And lastly the main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::wcout << "Press AnyKey" << std::endl;

    std::string SN = WMI_getHDDSN("C");

    std::wcout << "Error Message    : " << SN.c_str() << std::endl;

    _getch();
    _getch();

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you try:
hr = (pLoc)->ConnectServer

Comment: Hi @AmitShakya ... not working, because the data type is `IWbemLocator **pLoc`

Comment: Let me try your code once.